# Was it wrong to flag this review audit as not an answer?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, new-users

I failed a [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/9765349) in the first post queue on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32446777/2200659) answer:

> Happens to me when I define UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance in my Info.plist. It happens on iOS 9 (beta & GM) but not on 8.4.

To me that looks very much like a comment of the type "me too", at least not an answer. So I flagged it. Wrong thing to do - it has 34 upvotes.

Looking closer at it, I can absolutely understand why it could be considered an answer. But I would still like some second opinions on this - should I have flagged or not? Is it an edge case or is it clear?

Comment: Well, with the downvotes I'm sure it is going to accrue from this meta post, it won't be an audit anymore.

Comment: @TinyGiant My intention was not to unleash the meta effect.

Comment: Well, it only has one right now which I believe is enough to make it not an audit.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me. It's phrased a bit too colloquially for my tastes, but it gives a reason why the OP might see that error.

Comment: Yes, it does rather read like a comment, nor does it actually give a solution to the problem.  However one of the comments on that question (by Olie) actually does gives a solution that people have said works, was re-posted as answer later

Comment: Yes, it's an answer, because the OP was actually asking "What part of my code relates to this"? And this answers that. I think an edit rather than a downvote is in order.

Comment: <rant>It's rubbish like this that convinced me to stay off SO a year back. People put in honest effort and are down voted (on answers), or told *you fail* on reviews.</rant>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was unfortunately worded, and caught you out in review. I'd have failed that audit too.

However, it is a valid answer and I have now edited it to read as such.